# how can I know how many time take my google script to run

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiples script running into a spreadsheet. I want to know how many time take the script to finish in sec.

I needs this information to find a way to tunned these script.

I know my question is very simple but i don't know How to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Execution Transcript after running the script. Click `View -- Execution Transcript` in your script editor

Comment: The script run in OnEdit, but the Execution Transcript not show anything. I needs to add any line to the script to view the time execution?

Comment: I found the problem, I want to know how many time the script take to run the last time. I mean the script is running OnEdit by multiples user. I see the View -- Execution Transcript only show the information when I run it. But if other user run it not showme the time for that execution